Release notes for Firefox-esr 115.11.0 is still not released by Mozilla. But Apt suggests an upgrade. Is it normal?
I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed along with XFCE. And I have installed firefox-esr via their ppa, in it.

Running apt-upgrade today suggested an update for firefox-esr from version 115.10.0 to 115.11.0. However, it seems the Mozilla website doesn't have a release note for 115.11.1, yet (screenshot attached).
Is this normal for apt (or, for that matter, for any package manager) to make an update that has no release notes, available to users?
I'm asking the question because my understanding is that only with a release note, a package manager can decide whether to recommend an update or not (for compatibility, security, etc).
May be a novice question, but I'm curious to know what's behind the decision.

This seems to be normal, I experience this most of times when Firefox is upgraded.
apt and as far as I know any other package manager do not check for release notes.
If the maintainer of a repository upload a new version for a package, it means that the package is upgradable. The package is build for your version of Ubuntu and should be therefor compatible, if it is not, that would be a bug.
Regarding security you should read at https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa :

You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding ppa:mozillateam/ppa to your system's Software Sources

It's up to you to trust this ppa and the software provided by it or not.
That Mozilla lags behind with the release notes is most probably caused by lag of man power, remind that a lot of work is done by volunteers. But they want to publish new versions (which probably include important security fixes) as fast as possible.
